# what is the Event which occurs repeatedly for UIButton in ios?

Tags: ios

Can we make it so that if the user holds their finger down on the button so that the method calls repeatedly automatically until user removes their finger on button?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UILongPressGestureRecognizer for this purpose. Add your button to the   UILongPressGestureRecognizer . The UILongPressGestureRecognizer has two states:

```
1.UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
2.UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

In first state use timer to call any defined method continuously . and  in second method cancel that timer So that method will no longer called.